# TypeScript object method and nested object bearing the same name

Tags: javascript, typescript

I'm working on a utility function that converts any velocity unit into m/s, then into whatever unit you're after. I've made a `Convert` object with `.from` and `.to` methods which is called using `Convert.velocity.from(unit, value)` and `Convert.velocity.to(unit, value)`.

Now I want to add a method `Convert.velocity(fromUnit, value, toUnit)` that handles the entire conversion, but I can't figure out how to set up the method `.velocity()` with the same name as the nested object `.velocity`. I'm sure it's possible.

### Code

```js
interface ConversionUnits {
  "km/h": number;
  "mi/h": number;
  "m/s": number;
}

type ValidSpeedUnit = "km/h" | "mi/h" | "m/s"

const msMultipliers: ConversionUnits = {
  "km/h": 0.2777777778,
  "mi/h": 0.44704,
  "m/s": 1
}
const msDividers: ConversionUnits = {
  "km/h": 3.6,
  "mi/h": 2.2369362921,
  "m/s": 1
}

const Convert = {
  velocity: {
    from: (unit: ValidSpeedUnit, value: number): number => value * msMultipliers[unit],
    to: (unit: ValidSpeedUnit, value: number): number => value * msDividers[unit]
  },
  velocity: (fromUnit: ValidSpeedUnit, value: number, toUnit: ValidSpeedUnit) => this.velocity.to(toUnit, this.velocity.from(fromUnit, value))
}
```

### Expected Result

```js
console.log(Convert.velocity.from("mi/h", 200))    //  89.41  m/s
console.log(Convert.velocity.to("km/h", 89.41))    // 321.88 km/h
console.log(Convert.velocity("mi/h", 200, "km/h")) // 321.88 km/h
```

Comment: `I'm sure it's possible.`  No, you can't have the same object property names,  you could have some overload functions though..

Comment: @Keith but `.velocity()` has more parameters than `.from()` and `.to()`..

Comment: You don't have 3 functions called velocity here.   You have 3 functions called   `from / to / velocity`, and a property called `velocity`, you can't have another property called velocity.  You could have a function called velocity that has overloads that do all 3..

Comment: Okey, yes, "properties" is the word I'm missing. I don't actually have any programmer colleagues or hangout buddies, so the terminology takes a while to memorize. Thank you for reminding me :)

Comment: API-wise I think your Convert.velocity should be a simple function with overloads which takes an object as parameter : `{ value: number, from: unit }` converts to m/s ; `{ value: number, to: unit }` converts from m/s to the provided unit `{ value: number, from: unit, to: unit}` converts between 2 units. This would be more tidy and familiar, in my opinion.

Comment: @geoffrey Yes, my thought exactly! I'm refactoring the code as we speak.

Comment: @OlegValter Ok, thanks for letting me know :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't believe there is a "literal" syntax for defining a function along with properties, but this works:

```
const Convert = (() => {
  const from = (unit: ValidSpeedUnit, value: number): number => value * msMultipliers[unit]
  const to = (unit: ValidSpeedUnit, value: number): number => value * msDividers[unit]
  const func = (fromUnit: ValidSpeedUnit, value: number, toUnit: ValidSpeedUnit) => to(toUnit, from(fromUnit, value))
  func.from = from
  func.to = to
  return {
    velocity: func
  }
})()
```

Inferred type:

```
const Convert: {
    velocity: {
        (fromUnit: ValidSpeedUnit, value: number, toUnit: ValidSpeedUnit): number;
        from: (unit: ValidSpeedUnit, value: number) => number;
        to: (unit: ValidSpeedUnit, value: number) => number;
    };
}
```

Comment: Wow! This worked perfectly! What is this technique called? I need to learn more

Comment: @CasperTollefsen  Not sure there is a special name,  but what is happening here is that an IIFE has been used to create a function, functions in Javascript are just objects, and then just adds 2 new properties called `from` and `to`,.  It's certainly one way, the only downside is that your code completion is going to get all of the function prototypes like `apply / bind / call / toString / caller` etc, so your `to` & `from` will be less obvious..

Comment: IIFE stands for "immediately invoked function expression". The purpose of creating a closure where local variables are defined and returning a function is to emulate a module system. CommonJS and ES2015 modules make it obsolete. IIFE closures are also used to avoid some problems when referencing an iterator in a loop, but Array methods such as `forEach` also made this practice obsolete. You really rarely see this in modern code.

Comment: @Keith Yes, I see.. I plan on using this as a module so making the methods stand out would be nice. I'm trying to utilize block-comments that can point out my custom methods.

Answer (score 0):

One option is to create a single function velocity, either with function overloads, or union interfaces..

Personally I like interfaces..

So based on your example ->

```js
interface velocityToParams {
  unit:ValidSpeedUnit;
  to:number
}

interface velocityFromParams {
  unit:ValidSpeedUnit;
  from:number
}

interface velocityCombinedParams {
  fromUnit: ValidSpeedUnit;
  toUnit: ValidSpeedUnit;
  value: number;
}

type velocityParams = velocityToParams | velocityFromParams | velocityCombinedParams;

const Convert = {
  velocity: (p:velocityParams):number => {
    if ('from' in p) {
      return p.from * msMultipliers[p.unit]
    } else if ('to' in p) {
      return p.to * msDividers[p.unit]
    } else {
      return  Convert.velocity({to: Convert.velocity({from: p.value, unit: p.fromUnit}), unit:p.toUnit})
    }
  }
}

//and then they would be called like
Convert.velocity({from: 1, unit: 'km/h'});
Convert.velocity({to: 1, unit: 'km/h'});
Convert.velocity({fromUnit: 'km/h', toUnit: 'm/s', value: 1})
```